# Issues authenticating OAuth with Azure bot Service

Tags: azure-active-directory, botframework

I recently wrote a c# bot using botframework (v4) that connects to users' account through oAuth (aadv2). I followed this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) for the azure setup.

For most users, it's working perfectly fine but a small part of them can't get the magic code.

Instead they got a 404 after login in AD portal)

[image: emulator can't login]
Here's the result of a curl against the auth url :

```
curl https://token.botframework.com/api/oauth/signin?signin=921d46120f2743bfe0e82b4c859898cda9bec041f8 -v -L

< Location: https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/login/6cea70f5-7239-3769-57ce-9e90e9003dcc_aaaf9313-e069-86b0-6a34?redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2ftoken.botframework.com%2fapi%2foauth%2fPostSignInCallback%3fsignin%3d921d46120f2743bfe0e82b4c859898cda9bec041f8

> GET /.auth/web/login/6cea70f5-7239-3769-57ce-9e90e9003dcc_aaaf9313-e069-86b0-6a34?redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2ftoken.botframework.com%2fapi%2foauth%2fPostSignInCallback%3fsignin%3d921d46120f2743bfe0e82b4c859898cda9bec041f8 HTTP/1.1
> Host: token.botframework.com
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Content-Length: 103
< Content-Type: text/html
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Date: Thu, 13 Dec 2018 16:28:12 GMT
<
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.* Connection #0 to host token.botframework.com left intact
```

And as I said, it's working for most of the users perfectly fine so I don't think it's a configuration issue in the portal or in the bot...

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: Not currently, it happens from time to time...

Answer (score -1):

I have this issue also.  It started about one weeks ago.

No solution as yet - have raised it with MS Bot Framework Team.

Comment: This should be entered as a comment to the question, not as an answer.