# Azure ADv2 - token.botframework.com resource not found

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, botframework

I have a bot hosted in Azure which uses AADv2 authentication. The authentication was working perfectly until today, when it is throwing an error ("The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable") although I didn't change anything in the bot code or configuration.

I believe it is related with Azure rather than the bot's code since I test the connection from Azure Oauth Settings and it gives me the same error page:
"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable".

This is where I test my connection:
[image]

I followed the instructions given by Microsoft to implement AADv2 in a bot:

- Registered an app in apps.dev.microsoft as a Web Platform with redirect URL: https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect
- Added OAuth Connection Setting to my bot

I believe it is not relevant, but just in case: the bot is developed with NodeJS using the BotFrameworkv4.

Comment: Is it the same as this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53766505/issues-authenticating-oauth-with-azure-bot-service

Comment: I also have the issue (in 1 computer but in all browsers on that computer).

Comment: I also have this issue. 1 bot that worked now no longer works and 1 new bot on a different tenant doesn't work. I have a third tenant where it still works (using new or existing AAD app).

Comment: @thomasmartinsen yes it definitely is related, although he/she says that it works for some people and for me doesn't work for anyone. Thank you for the link since I didn't found anything related!

Comment: @jbeltran I have filed a bug on github - https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/1245

Comment: We did not change anything in our code, things suddenly started working again on all our tenants..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems to work fine now.

We didn't change anything in the code before or after the error and the authentication is back to normal again. I suppose it was an AAD internal error.

Microsoft answered the issue opened by @thomasmartinsen above, apparently there was a faulty service instance causing this problem, it is now repaired.